# Can I pass a list of strings as "old" in str.replace(old, new[, count])?

Tags: python, replace

I am cleaning a lot of data and calling replace() for every string/character that I want to replace is not difficult but I want to know if it can be done this way.

What I am thinking is:

```
to_be_replaced = ['\n' , '\t' , '"']
str.replace(to_be_replaced, '')
```

Would this work?

Comment: Did you try it? What did the error say ?

Comment: No, you can't. You can do it with `re.sub()` and a regexp that matches any of those characters.

Comment: No, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)